# How can I test system services?

Tags: android, android-espresso, fingerprint, ui-testing

I need a way to test system service in espresso.

Imaging to want test code below in espresso:

```
fingerprintManagerCompat = FingerprintManagerCompat.from(this);
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

if (!fingerprintManagerCompat.isHardwareDetected()) {
            showError("your device doesn't have finger print scanner");
}
```

So how I can test `isHardwareDetected()` method with false and true condition?

I don't have any idea what can I do in this situation, and how test this part of code.

Comment: Isn't it called "Espresso"?

Comment: @UweKeim yes my fault!